# Indefinite Integration involving trigonometric functions

Tags: integration

How do you integrate the following?

$$\int {3\sin{x}+4\over({3+4\sin{x}})^2}\,dx$$

Comment: Hi could you use MathJax environment https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference ? What have you tried for your integral ?

Comment: $\int ({3sinx+4 \over {3+4sinx}})^2dx$ or $\int {3sinx+4 \over ({3+4sinx})^2}dx$ ?  It seems you forgot a bracket.

Comment: The second one is what I meant

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this

Comment: tangent half angle formulas (popularly named Weierstrass sub) comes to mind. You will end up with a rational integral with a quadratic polynomial in the numerator and a quartic in the denominator. There are similar problems like these on this site

Comment: I've tried that ,didn't work

Comment: @STORMCR Please post your working as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$multiply \ the \ numerator \ and \ denominator \ by \ {sec^2}(x) 
\\ to \ get \ the \ integral \ as \int{\frac{3sec(x)tan(x)+4{sec^2}(x)}{{(3sec(x) \ + \ 4tan(x))}^2}}dx
\\ now \ subsitute \ 3sec(x) + 4tan(x) \ = \ t \ \Rightarrow \ dt = 3sec(x)tan(x) + 4{sec^2}(x)
\\ now \ the \ integral \ is \int{\frac{dt}{t^2}} \ = \ -\frac{1}{t} + C
\\ = -\frac{1}{3sec(x) \ + \ 4tan(x)} \ + \ C  $

Comment: Thank you,Helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

A good start would be to use this:
$$\int\frac{(3sin(x)+4)}{(4sin(x)+3)^2}$$ 
Can be written as 
$$\int\frac{(\frac{3}{4}(4sin(x)+3))}{(4sin(x)+3)^2}+\int\frac{\frac{7}{4}}{(4sin(x)+3)^2}$$ 
which then simplifies to 
$$\frac{3}{4}\int\frac{1}{4sin(x)+3}+\frac{7}{4}\int\frac{1}{(4sin(x)+3)^2}$$
Then you can try to apply Weierstrauss on the two separate integrals